# Match the elements of a vector defined over an abstract base class against a concrete derived class

Tags: c++, googlemock

Suppose I have the following abstract base class:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void method() = 0;
    virtual const bool operator==(const Base& other) const = 0;
};
```

And a concrete derived class.

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    int value_;
    Derived(int value) : value_(value) { }
    virtual void method() { }
    virtual const bool operator==(const Base& other) const {
        const Derived& derived = dynamic_cast<const Derived&>(other);
        return operator==(derived);
    }
    virtual const bool operator==(const Derived& other) const {
        return value_ == other.value_;
    }
};
```

Using Google Mock, I now want to assert that a vector defined over the base class contains an example of a concrete class

```
TEST(ArrayContents, CompareAgainstDerivedClassElements) {
    Derived d1(0);
    Derived d2(0);
    std::vector<Base*> v { &d1 };
    ASSERT_THAT(v, Contains( Pointee(d2) ));
}
```

C++ complains that it cannot create the `Eq` matcher because `Base` is an abstract class.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Eq'
note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = perseus::Base]: parameter type 'perseus::Base' is an abstract class
```

When I change `Base` so it's not abstract anymore:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void method() { }
    virtual const bool operator==(const Base& other) const { return false; }
};
```

C++ throws a `std::bad_cast` exception at the `dynamic_cast` expression.

Is such an assertion possible with Google Mock?

Comment: IMO a virtuell comparison operator is a code smell. Either you have value classes which you can easily compare instances of, or your have a polymorphic class hierarchy. (For starters, what happens of an object of the type `my_derived` is passed to the virtual operator?)

Comment: You're probably right that it's a code smell. And it turns out that I can move the dynamic cast into the assertion call.

Comment: I face very similar issue but in std::generate_n. It complains that I pass the reference to the base class. But the solution below doesn't work in my case since the I don't know the derived class at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that the solution is to use the `WhenDynamicCastTo` matcher:

```
ASSERT_THAT(v, Contains( WhenDynamicCastTo<Derived*>(Pointee(d2)) ));
```

This way, I also don't need the virtual `operator==` methods.

Comment: error: 'WhenDynamicCastTo' was not declared in this scope

Comment: You have to qualify all matchers with `::testing::`, e.g. `::testing::WhenDynamicCastTo<...>`, add `using ::testing::WhenDynamicCastTo` [declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations), or `using namespace ::testing` [using directive](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives).